# Numpy select rows with multiple columns as criteria

Tags: python, numpy

say you have following array

```
a = np.array([[-1,-2,-3,4],[6,-1,-3,-4],[3,2,5,6]])
```

and you want all rows, where position 0, 1 and 2 are < 0.

So far i found follwing unelegant solutions:

```
b = a[np.logical_and(a[:, 0]<0, a[:, 1]<0, a[:, 2]<0)]
```

or

```
c= a[np.where((a[:, 0]<0) * (a[:, 1]<0) * (a[:, 2]<0))]
```

considering that i want to deal with huge arrays, that would be a pretty bad way to solve it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
b = a[np.all(a[:,:3] < 0,axis=1)]
```

So you can first construct a submatrix by using *slicing* `a[:,:3]` will construct a matrix for the first three columns of the matrix a. Next we use `< 0` to check if all these elements are less than zero.

We then will perform a *logical and* on every row (by anding the columns together). This will construct a 1D matrix for every row. An element will be `True` if all the three columns are `True`. Otherwise it is `False`.

Finally we use *masking* to construct a submatrix where the first three columns are *all* less than 0. This will probably work faster since the *number* of numpy calls is less and thus we do more work per call.

Comment: Thanks you are my hero